# Android Emulator stays with black screen after trying a lot of things to fix it

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

My Android emulator starts but do not progress from the black screen, it happened from one day to another a few days after installing Android Studio 4.0. I tried the next things:

- Reinstall completely from zero Android Studio
- Installing/Uninstalling Android Emulator, Intel Xahm, Android Platform Tools
- Creating and deleting New devices in the avd Manager with differentes images of Android
- Put Graphics to Software or hardware and unable device frame
- Rebooting pc multiple times
- Invalidate Cache and Restart

Through the cli of Windows I run this command to try to get detail errors and nothing that i found worked

[image: Windows CLI Details]

Emulator stay this way till the message of "Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online"

[image]

## Solution

I had Vanguard software from Valorant running on background causing this issue. I unninstalled it and it was fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried enabling hyper-virtualization from your BIOS?

1. It's important to check if you have at **least 2GB of HDD** space before starting it, usually, it turns to boot up slower if you are using a PC with less than **16 GB of RAM** for this new **Studio 4.0**.
   Check out [this link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-troubleshooting) for more info.
2. Also, check the amount of memory allocated to the Emulator, it should be probably higher than 512MB for a better experience.
3. Also, check the amount of memory allocated to the android studio by doing:
   *File -> Settings->Appearance & Behavior->Appearance*. In my case, a 6GB works just fine.

Comment: 1. Yes i have plenty of storage in my SSD where Andorid is installed, I have 32 GB of RAM
2. It has 1534 MB
3. I cant find in Appearance where to check the allocated memory to android studio.

Although I reboot to recheck Virtualization in BIOS it was already enabled but this time when my pc boot up the emulator work just fine, this is the second time it happens I am not sure which of the fixes got it